# Cannot Erase my old iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, wifi

I upgraded my iPhone 4S to a 6.  They transferred the number and everything in the Verizon store.  However, they did not want the old phone on trade in.  I would like to trade / sell or give away the old phone but I want to reset it first.

However, it will not let me reset it because it will not connect to the WiFi at my house in order to accept the iTunes password.

I have confirmed with other devices the WiFi is working and I am typing the correct iTunes password.  This is really frustrating me.

Comment: Why dont you restore your iphone using iTunes?

Comment: I am not trying to restore it.  I am trying to delete all the data.  The problem is it will not connect to the WiFi.  I also tried connecting through a hot spot on my new phone.

Comment: Sorry but Restoring == erase all data

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:
Try resetting it via iTunes. To do this: Plug your iPhone into your computer and open iTunes. In iTunes, select your iPhone device and click on "Restore iPhone". Let the process finish and the phone restart. After the restart you can plug it out of your computer. Now should your iPhone be reseted to factory defaults.

Method 2:
You say that you can't connect it to your Wi-Fi network. Have you tried with forgetting the network? To forget the network: Go into the Settings application -> Wi-Fi -> Tap on the little "i" at the same row as the name (SSID) of your Wi-Fi network.
Now you can try to reconnect to the Wi-Fi network again and see if it works better. If you are able to connect to the Wi-Fi network, then you can reset it via the Settings application.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with my iPhone 4s, but the problem was that my phone itself had problems connecting to WiFi in general. My solution was to put the SIM from my new iPhone in to the 4s (I had to use an adapter because the 4s uses micro SIM, not nano SIM), and over cellular data I could log in to my Apple ID and erase all content and settings.

If the other solutions here aren't working for you and your iPhone 4s can take a SIM either from your new phone or from somebody else's phone (you just need it long enough to get online and then you can return their SIM with no problem), this may work for you.